# Google Geocode API Giving Regional Data

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-geocoding-api, regional

I am working with [GeoCoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) API of Google.

I want to get English data always instead of regional language data.

I am calling this [API](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=19.9276734,75.0116544&key=%3CMY_API_KEY%3E) link and taking `formatted_address` = ***लासुरगाव रोड, लसुर, महाराष्ट्र 423702, India*** from the first position of `results` key which is in Hindi from following data:

```
{
   "plus_code" : {
      "compound_code" : "W2H6+3M Harsul, Maharashtra, India",
      "global_code" : "7JFQW2H6+3M"
   },
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "लासुरगाव रोड",
               "short_name" : "लासुरगाव रोड",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "लसुर",
               "short_name" : "लसुर",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "औरंगाबाद",
               "short_name" : "औरंगाबाद",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "महाराष्ट्र",
               "short_name" : "MH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "423702",
               "short_name" : "423702",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "लासुरगाव रोड, लसुर, महाराष्ट्र 423702, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 19.9279766,
                  "lng" : 75.011798
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 19.9276098,
                  "lng" : 75.0108685
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 19.9277932,
               "lng" : 75.01133329999999
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 19.9291421802915,
                  "lng" : 75.0126822302915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 19.9264442197085,
                  "lng" : 75.0099842697085
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJRS92AquJ2zsRGIY8TmId5OQ",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Lasur",
               "short_name" : "Lasur",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Aurangabad",
               "short_name" : "Aurangabad",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "short_name" : "MH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "423702",
               "short_name" : "423702",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Lasur, Maharashtra 423702, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 19.9365397,
                  "lng" : 75.0198626
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 19.9104756,
                  "lng" : 74.99952089999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 19.9282261,
               "lng" : 75.0114612
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 19.9365397,
                  "lng" : 75.0198626
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 19.9104756,
                  "lng" : 74.99952089999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJqakxlFSI2zsRU2QZ0WNgCMQ",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "423702",
               "short_name" : "423702",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Aurangabad",
               "short_name" : "Aurangabad",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "short_name" : "MH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Maharashtra 423702, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 19.9812906,
                  "lng" : 75.14881470000002
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 19.7257081,
                  "lng" : 74.7853344
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 19.8539262,
               "lng" : 74.9910112
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 19.9812906,
                  "lng" : 75.14881470000002
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 19.7257081,
                  "lng" : 74.7853344
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJAVBUmAp43DsRAohUV0LQMO4",
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Aurangabad",
               "short_name" : "Aurangabad",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "short_name" : "MH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Aurangabad, Maharashtra, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 20.6673799,
                  "lng" : 76.04805
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 19.37426,
                  "lng" : 74.58680009999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 19.8910826,
               "lng" : 75.1545381
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 20.6673799,
                  "lng" : 76.04805
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 19.37426,
                  "lng" : 74.58680009999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJOV9BNoai2zsRtocWKbhGxs8",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
               "short_name" : "MH",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Maharashtra, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.028441,
                  "lng" : 80.890924
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 15.6024121,
                  "lng" : 72.659363
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 19.7514798,
               "lng" : 75.7138884
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.028441,
                  "lng" : 80.890924
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 15.6024121,
                  "lng" : 72.659363
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ-dacnB7EzzsRtk_gS5IiLxs",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.513327,
                  "lng" : 97.39535869999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 6.4626999,
                  "lng" : 68.1097
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 20.593684,
               "lng" : 78.96288
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 35.513327,
                  "lng" : 97.39535869999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 6.4626999,
                  "lng" : 68.1097
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc",
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Is it possible to get `English` data only for every time as I don't want data in regional language?

### Edited:

What I have tried recently?

- Pass `Accept-Language=en` or `Accept-Language=en-US` in header but not working.
- tried with `language=en` and `hl=en` but not working.

Comment: Did you try adding language parameter: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=22.9997%2C72.6354&language=en&key=YOUR_API_KEY` ? Is result the same with specified language?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with `language=en` and also tried with `hl=en` but getting same result.

Comment: It sounds like a data issue, I mean missing translations in Google database. Try to reach out to the Google Maps support via your Cloud project interface.

Comment: Thank you @xomena , Actually I searched on Google Maps for this place. Its displaying data in both langulage English and Hindi.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it might be kind of intended behavior. Google favor local language in Geocoding API responses in case of address local language has the same alphabet as user language.

This behavior is explained in the following blog article

https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2014/11/localization-of-street-addresses-in.html

> If the local language and user language both use the same alphabet, the Geocoding API will now return the local names for the streets and localities. For example, searching for an address in Brazil with user language set to English now returns “Avenida Paulista” rather than “Paulista Avenue”.
>
> If the local language and user language use different alphabets, the Geocoding API will return the local name, transliterated into the Latin alphabet. In some cases, an English translation may be returned, for example if no transliteration is available. For example, searching for El Tahrir Square with user language set to Japanese now returns “El-Tahrir Square, Ismailia, Qasr an Nile, Cairo Governorate, エジプト” rather than “エジプト カイロ県 Qasr an Nile, タハリール広場” (the old result) or “ميدان التحرير، قصر النيل، محافظة القاهرة‬، مصر” (the local name).

Maybe Google detects that your IP address is located in India, so the response favor a local language.

In my case when I execute your sample request from my location in Spain I get response in English as following

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=22.9997%2C72.6354&key=MY_API_KEY`

```
{
  "plus_code":{
    "compound_code":"XJXP+V5 Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India","global_code":"7JJJXJXP+V5"
  },
  "results":[
    {
      "address_components":[
        {
          "long_name":"BRTS Corridor",
          "short_name":"BRTS Corridor",
          "types":[
            "route"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Rabari Colony",
          "short_name":"Rabari Colony",
          "types":[
            "political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Amraiwadi",
          "short_name":"Amraiwadi",
          "types":[
            "political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "short_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "types":[
            "locality","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "short_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_2","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Gujarat",
          "short_name":"GJ",
          "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_1","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"India",
          "short_name":"IN",
          "types":[
            "country","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"380008",
          "short_name":"380008",
          "types":[
            "postal_code"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"BRTS Corridor, Rabari Colony, Amraiwadi, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380008, India",
      "geometry":{
        "bounds":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":23.0048831,"lng":72.63708439999999
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":22.9996702,"lng":72.6353833
          }
        },
        "location":{
          "lat":23.0022759,"lng":72.6362362
        },
        "location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
        "viewport":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":23.0048831,"lng":72.6375828302915
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":22.9996702,"lng":72.6348848697085
          }
        }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJ9UjW5mqGXjkR2mRics2aU4I",
      "types":[
        "route"
      ]
    },
    {
      "address_components":[
        {
          "long_name":"Rabari Colony",
          "short_name":"Rabari Colony",
          "types":[
            "political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Amraiwadi",
          "short_name":"Amraiwadi",
          "types":[
            "political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "short_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "types":[
            "locality","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "short_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_2","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Gujarat",
          "short_name":"GJ",
          "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_1","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"India",
          "short_name":"IN",
          "types":[
            "country","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"380038",
          "short_name":"380038",
          "types":[
            "postal_code"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"Rabari Colony, Amraiwadi, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380038, India",
      "geometry":{
        "bounds":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":23.009061,"lng":72.6454679
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":22.9931311,"lng":72.6254739
          }
        },
        "location":{
          "lat":23.0019153,"lng":72.6343352
        },
        "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":23.009061,"lng":72.6454679
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":22.9931311,"lng":72.6254739
          }
        }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJaY70lGuGXjkRp_Y5g5vavs4",
      "types":[
        "political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "address_components":[
        {
          "long_name":"380026",
          "short_name":"380026",
          "types":[
            "postal_code"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "short_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "types":[
            "locality","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "short_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_2","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Gujarat",
          "short_name":"GJ",
          "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_1","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"India",
          "short_name":"IN",
          "types":[
            "country","political"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380026, India",
      "geometry":{
        "bounds":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":23.0113677,"lng":72.6453252
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":22.9891871,"lng":72.60732229999999
          }
        },
        "location":{
          "lat":23.0044623,"lng":72.62575869999999
        },
        "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":23.0113677,"lng":72.6453252
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":22.9891871,"lng":72.60732229999999
          }
        }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJ89jUeXOGXjkRICMp0qh6yZg",
      "types":[
        "postal_code"
      ]
    },
    {
      "address_components":[
        {
          "long_name":"Amraiwadi",
          "short_name":"Amraiwadi",
          "types":[
            "political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "short_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "types":[
            "locality","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "short_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_2","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Gujarat",
          "short_name":"GJ",
          "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_1","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"India",
          "short_name":"IN",
          "types":[
            "country","political"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"Amraiwadi, Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India",
      "geometry":{
        "bounds":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":23.0137105,"lng":72.645556
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":22.989467,"lng":72.61277
          }
        },
        "location":{
          "lat":22.9996728,"lng":72.635381
        },
        "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":23.0137105,"lng":72.645556
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":22.989467,"lng":72.61277
          }
        }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJJTsGyhKGXjkR96JPXxPnU-4",
      "types":[
        "political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"
      ]
    },
    {
      "address_components":[
        {
          "long_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "short_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "types":[
            "locality","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "short_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_2","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Gujarat",
          "short_name":"GJ",
          "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_1","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"India",
          "short_name":"IN",
          "types":[
            "country","political"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India",
      "geometry":{
        "bounds":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":23.1378156,"lng":72.7053737
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":22.9028759,"lng":72.4541115
          }
        },
        "location":{
          "lat":23.022505,"lng":72.5713621
        },
        "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":23.1378156,"lng":72.7053737
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":22.9028759,"lng":72.4541115
          }
        }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJSdRbuoqEXjkRFmVPYRHdzk8",
      "types":[
        "locality","political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "address_components":[
        {
          "long_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "short_name":"Ahmedabad",
          "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_2","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Gujarat",
          "short_name":"GJ",
          "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_1","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"India",
          "short_name":"IN",
          "types":[
            "country","political"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India",
      "geometry":{
        "bounds":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":23.50846,"lng":72.84009999999999
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":21.9817599,"lng":71.83994
          }
        },
        "location":{
          "lat":23.022475,"lng":72.5715183
        },
        "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":23.50846,"lng":72.84009999999999
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":21.9817599,"lng":71.83994
          }
        }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJIxcnN0CEXjkRobQIMyNYLpI",
      "types":[
        "administrative_area_level_2","political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "address_components":[
        {
          "long_name":"Gujarat",
          "short_name":"GJ",
          "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_1","political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"India",
          "short_name":"IN",
          "types":[
            "country","political"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"Gujarat, India",
      "geometry":{
        "bounds":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":24.705709,"lng":74.4764881
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":20.127954,"lng":68.162834
          }
        },
        "location":{
          "lat":22.258652,"lng":71.1923805
        },
        "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":24.705709,"lng":74.4764881
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":20.127954,"lng":68.162834
          }
        }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJlfcOXx8FWTkRLlJU7YfYG4Y",
      "types":[
        "administrative_area_level_1","political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "address_components":[
        {
          "long_name":"India",
          "short_name":"IN",
          "types":[
            "country","political"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"India",
      "geometry":{
        "bounds":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":35.513327,"lng":97.39535869999999
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":6.4626999,"lng":68.1097
          }
        },
        "location":{
          "lat":20.593684,"lng":78.96288
        },
        "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":35.513327,"lng":97.39535869999999
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":6.4626999,"lng":68.1097
          }
        }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc",
      "types":[
        "country","political"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status":"OK"
}
```

So, in order to get English results you should send requests from a server located outside your country, e.g. from Europe or try to convince Google that you are located outside India (maybe using VPN).

I hope this helps!

#### Update

The `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=19.9276734%2C75.0116544&key=MY_API_KEY` also gives results in Hindi for me.

Note that the type of result is "route" and place Id is `ChIJRS92AquJ2zsRGIY8TmId5OQ`.

If I open this place ID in Geocoder tool the text is also in Hindi

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJRS92AquJ2zsRGIY8TmId5OQ

If you execute place details request `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJRS92AquJ2zsRGIY8TmId5OQ&key=YOUR_API_KEY` you will see in response direct link on Google maps for this place

https://maps.google.com/?q=%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B5+%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A1,+%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0,+%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9F%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0+423702,+India&ftid=0x3bdb89ab02762f45:0xe4e41d624e3c8618

The text in Google maps is also in Hindi.

It looks like place with id `ChIJRS92AquJ2zsRGIY8TmId5OQ` that represents a route indeed has a data issue on Google side.

I think the only way to fix it is contacting Google Maps API support team. Hopefully they can help with this data issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. Have you tried [THIS](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=19.9276734,75.0116544&key=MY_API_KEY) latlong, I am getting Hindi language in this latlong. The latlong used by you is giving me same result in English.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I have contacted to Google API Team, They will let me know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding region parameter: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=22.9997%2C72.6354&language=en&region=EG&key=YOUR_API_KEY ?

Comment: `region` is used to get results of specific region only. If we are passing `Rajkot` to find without region then it will get result of India as well as Pakistan because both country has `Rajkot` city. If we pass region=IN then it will get for India only.